# How to send an object from a form to redux saga function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react redux in an application.

I am trying to send an object from react component to redux request.

Whenever any user fill registration form and submit a form
then a dispatcher send a request to registerRequest action.

Please see in tried code

```
-- RegisterRequest.js

import {
    REGISTER_REQUESTING
    } from '../../constants/register'
    
const registerRequest = function registerRequest (data) {
          return {
            type: REGISTER_REQUESTING,
            data
          }
        }   
    
        export default registerRequest
```

See the form submit call

```
const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();     
    dispatch(registerRequest(data));
  };
```

See the complete component file

```
---- RegisterComponent.js ---------------------
 
import React from 'react';
import history from './history';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { connect,useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import registerRequest from './actions/registerrequest';

export default function RegisterComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { register, handleSubmit,reset, errors} = useForm();

  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();     
    dispatch(registerRequest(data));
  };

  return (
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                required
                inputRef={register}
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                required
                inputRef={register}
                id="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                name="lastName"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                inputRef={register}
                id="emailAddress"
                label="Email Address"
                name="emailAddress"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth            
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>        
  );
}    

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  registerU: state.registerU,  
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    registerU: (data) => {
      dispatch(registerRequest(data))
    }
  }
}

connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterComponent);
```

I want to know am I doing it in a correct way ? What I need to send a complete object from the form submit to get data from server side for saving registration details.

**I don't know either this is best or latest practice or not but I am using redux sage.**

My registerRequest action is receiving form data and displaying while I am debugging the application but then I get an error.  I don't know why my request is not taking an object parameter and I don't know how redux saga receive it.

I am showing the code of my saga file below:

```
----RegisterSaga.js----

import { take, fork, cancel, call, put, cancelled } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import history from './history';
import Api from './api';
import { handleApiErrors } from './api-errors';
import {
  REGISTER_REQUESTING,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_ERROR,
} from './constants/register'    

import {
  setClient,
  unsetClient,
} from './actions/customerinfo'

import {
  CLIENT_UNSET,
} from './customerInfo'    

async function registerU(data){      
  try {      
    const { user } = data;
    let res = await Api.post('/Create/Register', {user});
    let response = await res.json();
    return response;
  }
 catch (e) {
        return e;
  } 
}

function* registerFlow (user) {  
  let token;
    try {      
    token = yield call(registerU,user)           

    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token))

  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: REGISTERUSER_ERROR, error })
  } finally {
  }   
  return token
}

// Our watcher (saga)
function* registerWatcher () {
  while (true) {
    const { user } = yield take(REGISTER_REQUESTING);

    const task = yield fork(registerFlow, user);        
  }
}

export default registerWatcher

--- Index for saga ----

import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import RegisterSaga from './register';

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all(RegisterSaga()]);
}
```

What should I do to fix in code?

```
Application built with
{
  "react": "16.13.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5"
}
```

The problem I face is getting an undefined variable user in

```
function* registerFlow (user)
```

For the above function, registerU function receives undefined parameter and it restrict the server side call.

I think the issue belong to these line of code under watcher.

```
 const { user } = yield take(REGISTER_REQUESTING);
 const task = yield fork(registerFlow, user);
```

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations for send objects but could not find the recommended way to solve the the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already dispatching in mapDispatchToProps so need of dispatching again in onSubmit.

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
e.preventDefault();     
props.registerRequest(data);
```

};

Comment: Hi Thank you user8. but I don't think so you get my point well. please read my question again i am not using es6 base classes. My submit function is correct and receiving data.
See this function, this is wrong.  token = yield call(registerU,user)  because user is undefined and there is some issue in registerRequest s well

Comment: Thank you guys. my problem has been solve. i used  user = {} in function registerRequest (user = {}),  function* registerFlow (user = {}),  and const user = {} = yield take(REGISTER_REQUESTING); and it worked.